# How to remove duplicates using awk in 1th~46th column of 47 field csv file?

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv, duplicate

I have a bash script to combine many files into a single csv file.
This csv file has 47 fields and several 10000 rows.

To remove duplicates I was using `awk '!seen[$0]++'` however, for sorting I have added a reference to the originating source in column 47.

I still only want to index on column 1 to 46 and print all including 47.

Must I list all 46 as in `awk '!seen[$1, $2, $3, ,..etc.., $45, $46]++`' or is there an easier way?

Comment: post a few input lines and expected result for them

Comment: Maybe a for loop...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ cat file
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
1 2 3 x
a b c d
5 6 7 y
```

Looking at the first 3 fields as the "key", we want to drop the 2nd "1 2 3" and the 2nd "5 6 7" lines

```
awk '
    {
        line = $0     # remember the original state of this line
        NF--          # forget about the last field
    }
    !seen[$0]++ {print line}   # if the "new" line is unique, print the "old" line
' file
```

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
a b c d
```

Comment: I see I'm duplicating @hauke's answer. making community wiki

Comment: I had to change  line = $0  to  line = $47 to get this to work and as I am working with a comma separated file I also amended the print line to {print $0 "," line}

Answer (score 1):

```
'sort_field=$47; $47=""; !seen[$0]++ { print $0 " " sort_field }'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `sort` and print unique lines with its uniqe `-u` option based on 1~46 fields `k1,46`?

```
sort -uk1,46 infile.txt
```

if your input files is a .csv comma separated, you can specify that with `-t','`.

```
sort -t',' -uk1,46 infile.txt
```

For below input as sample:

```
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
1,2,3,x
a,b,c,d
5,6,7,y
```

The output is:

```
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
a,b,c,d
```